# Add text after hyperlink without including it in the hyperlink

Tags: adobe-indesign

In InDesign, when you add a hyperlink to a text while writing and then continue writing after the hyperlink, everything you add will be included in the hyperlink. Here are two pictures for illustration:

[image: stat 1]

[image: state 2]

As you can see, I added a hyperlink to the word 'hyperlink'. Then I wrote ' more text', which got unintentionally added to the hyperlink.

Now the only thing I can do to stop any subsequent text from getting added to the hyperlink is to delete it, mark the word 'hyperlink' again and add the hyperlink a second time. As a workaround, I try to type in the next space character after the word and then only mark the word itself before adding the hyperlink. This way, everything I write after the space won't be included in the hyperlink. But sometimes I forget to do that and the only thing I can do is delete the hyperlink and then add it again, which is somewhat frustrating.

Is there a better way? That is, either have new text **not** added to the hyperlink text or remove ' more text' from the hyperlink text without deleting the hyperlink entirely? I would be happy with a way to do either of those things. Thank you!

Comment: I've tried to figure this out myself and had no luck.  What I've done is make a character style that makes my font that will be links stand out, temporarily apply it, as I'm entering my copy, then go back and add my links in, after the copy has been entered.  Hopefully someone gives us a better method! haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 methods I have found, 1 of which is a workaround and not a solution.

1) Change the character style for the text you do not want to be hyperlinked.

When you first create a hyperlink, InDesign will create a new hyperlink character style called "Hyperlink". Select the text you do not want to be hyperlinked and change the character style.

2) This is a workaround and not a solution. Add a space after the text you want hyperlinked. After you add the space select only the text you want to link and create the hyperlink.

Comment: 2) is what I have been doing, as mentioned in the question. 1) works though! I didn't expect that the hyperlink was tied to the character style with the same name, but apparently it is. Thanks!